# Listing mounted filesystems

Tags: filesystems, mount

What command may I use to list the currently mounted filesystems on a Unix system?

Comment: Next time, write the question in the text of the question itself, not just in the title. Also consider the fact that we are volunteers here. _Demanding_ an answer is incredibly rude.

Comment: Also read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Considering the trouble what Linuxes are doing with the mount table in the last decade, I can't think that this question would be bad. If you think it is, then enter a `mount` command and see the page-long crap what you get back. Yes, this question is dupe, but it is not a bad question.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `mount`.

If you have something you'd like to do but don't know what command to use to do it, use the `apropos` command:

```
apropos mount
```

The `mount` command is the first one listed on my OpenBSD system.

Reading its manual:

> The system maintains a list of currently mounted file systems.  If no
>        arguments are given to `mount`, this list is printed.

Answer (score 2):

There are more than one possibility for that. I prefer: (as root or with `sudo`)
`lsblk -f`. It shows the device name, the filesystem, the UUID, and the mount point, and is well formated to read it. You can simply use `mount` but this shows also the virtual filesystems like `/proc`, `/sys`, `/tmpfs` and so on.

Comment: There is no indication that the user is using Linux, though.

Comment: Although I admit that is is highly probable.